# Why using EnTT process fails to compile

Tags: c++

I'm following https://github.com/skypjack/entt/wiki/Crash-Course:-cooperative-scheduler to evaluate EnTT library 3.2.2

Using VS2019 Community edition. It fails to compile.

```
#include <entt/entt.hpp>

struct my_process : entt::process<my_process, std::int32_t> {
  using delta_type = std::uint32_t;

  void update(delta_type delta, void *) {
    remaining -= std::min(remaining, delta);

    if (!remaining) {
      succeed();
    }
  }

private:
  delta_type remaining{1000u};
};

int main() {
  entt::scheduler<std::uint32_t> scheduler;

  scheduler.attach<my_process>("foobar");
}
```

Attach it to the scheduler

```
scheduler.attach<my_process>("foobar");
```

These are the build errors.

```
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build>cmake --build .
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  EnttTest.cpp
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(178,28): error C2607:  static assertion failed [C:\Use
rs\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxproj]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\EnttTest.cpp(21): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'a 
uto entt::scheduler<uint32_t>::attach<my_process,const char(&)[7]>(const char (&)[7])' being compiled [C:\Users\tunca\ 
source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxproj]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(179,69): error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert  
from 'initializer list' to 'my_process' [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxproj]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(177,1): message :  No constructor could take the sourc
e type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxpro 
j]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(179,60): error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert  
from 'initializer list' to 'entt::scheduler<uint32_t>::process_handler::instance_type' [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\en 
tt-test\build\entt-test.vcxproj]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(177,1): message :  No constructor could take the sourc 
e type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxpro 
j]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(177,1): error C3536:  'proc': cannot be used before it 
 is initialized [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxproj]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(180,42): error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert  
from 'int' to 'entt::scheduler<uint32_t>::process_handler::instance_type' [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build 
\entt-test.vcxproj]
C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt\src\entt\process/scheduler.hpp(177,1): message :  No constructor could take the sourc 
e type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous [C:\Users\tunca\source\repos\entt-test\build\entt-test.vcxpro 
j]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static assert that is failing is this one:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<process<Proc, Delta>, Proc>);
```

It's failing because the `Delta` template argument passed to `entt::scheduler` (`std::uint32_t`) doesn't match the `Delta` template argument used in the base of `my_process` (`std::int32_t`). Just change your struct declaration to match to get rid of this error.

```cpp
struct my_process : entt::process<my_process, std::uint32_t> { /* ... */ };
```

The other errors appear to be because `scheduler::attach<T>` forwards its arguments to the constructor of `T`. So, you need to add a constructor that accepts `"foobar"`:

```cpp
my_process (const char*) { /* whatever you want to do with it... */ }
```

After that, it compiles:

https://godbolt.org/z/8dEzww

Comment: Thanks mate ✔...This surprised me alot!
```#include <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skypjack/entt/master/single_include/entt/entt.hpp>
```